# Collection that contains no a where a⊆b and b is in the collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need a collection that disregards elements that are included in others:

```
Picky(Set(1, 2)) + Set(1) should equal(Picky(Set(1, 2)))

Picky(Set(1)) + Set(1, 2) should equal(Picky(Set(1, 2)))

Picky(Set(1, 3)) + Set(1, 2) should equal(Picky(Set(1, 3), Set(1, 2)))

Picky(Set(1, 2), (Set(1))) should equal(Picky(Set(1, 2)))
```

I actually have a solution

```
case class Picky[T] private(sets: Set[Set[T]]) {
  def +(s: Set[T]): Picky[T] = Picky(Picky.internalAddition(this.sets, s))
}

object Picky {
  def apply[T](sets: Set[T]*): Picky[T] = 
    Picky((Set[Set[T]]() /: sets)(internalAddition(_, _)))

  private def internalAddition[T](c: Set[Set[T]], s: Set[T]): Set[Set[T]] =
    if (c.exists(s subsetOf _)) c else c.filterNot(_ subsetOf s) + s
}
```

But I wonder whether there's already a collection that includes this concept, because what I'm trying to do sounds a bit like a set with a kind of reduction function, something like the following imaginary collection that accepts a `worse` function (`(a, b) => a subset b` in our specific case):

```
PickySet(){(a, b) => a subset b}
```

Where for any to elements (a, b) if `worse(a, b)` returned `true`, `a` would be discarded

To clarify the difference with Set, a Set would be a special case of PickySet:

```
PickySet(){_ == _}
```

Comment: It seems to me, that you just want `Set`-semantics. Where's the difference?

Comment: Sets discard repeated elements
  Set(1, 1) == Set(1)  also Set(Set(1), Set(1)) == Set(Set(1))
I'm looking for a collection that discards the worst of two elements
  Picky(Set(1, 2), Set(1)) == Picky(Set(1, 2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a convenient ready-made implementation of this collection, but you can make yours a little more general by using [`scala.math.PartialOrdering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/PartialOrdering.html) and the fact that sets are partially ordered by the subset relation.

First for the definition of `Picky`. In effect what you want is a container holding only [maximal elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element), where no elements are ordered with respect to each other, and all smaller elements have been deleted.

```
class Picky[A: PartialOrdering] private(val xs: Seq[A]) {
  def +(y: A): Picky[A] = new Picky(Picky.add(xs, y))
  override def toString = "Picky(%s)".format(xs.mkString(", "))
}

object Picky {
  def apply[A: PartialOrdering](xs: A*): Picky[A] =
    new Picky(xs.foldLeft(Seq.empty[A])(add))

  private def add[A](xs: Seq[A], y: A)(implicit ord: PartialOrdering[A]) = {
    val notSmaller = xs.filterNot(ord.lteq(_, y))
    if (notSmaller.exists(ord.lteq(y, _))) notSmaller else notSmaller :+ y
  }
}
```

Next for the partial ordering for sets, which is only defined if one of the sets is a subset of the other (possibly trivially):

```
implicit def subsetOrdering[A] = new PartialOrdering[Set[A]] {
   def tryCompare(x: Set[A], y: Set[A]) =
     if (x == y) Some(0)
     else if (x subsetOf y) Some(-1)
     else if (y subsetOf x) Some(1)
     else None

   def lteq(x: Set[A], y: Set[A]) =
     this.tryCompare(x, y).map(_ <= 0).getOrElse(false)
}
```

The following equivalent definition of `tryCompare` could conceivably be a little faster:

```
def tryCompare(x: Set[A], y: Set[A]) = {
  val s = (x & y).size
  if (s == x.size || s == y.size) Some(x.size - y.size) else None
}
```

Now we get the desired results:

```
scala> Picky(Set(1, 2)) + Set(1)
res0: Picky[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Picky(Set(1, 2))

scala> Picky(Set(1)) + Set(1, 2)
res1: Picky[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Picky(Set(1, 2))

scala> Picky(Set(1, 3)) + Set(1, 2)
res2: Picky[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Picky(Set(1, 3), Set(1, 2))

scala> Picky(Set(1, 2), (Set(1)))
res3: Picky[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Picky(Set(1, 2))
```

Note that we could very easily define an alternative partial ordering that would give `Picky` plain old set semantics (i.e., only equal things are ordered with respect to each other, and they're always equal).

Comment: What you've posted is not a ready-made collection but places the problem within a more general concept, that is want I wanted.

Thank you! I helps me understand.

PS, would you recommend any source for this kind of theory? (I'm being greedy now)